# Does the twitter api still support auto following and unfollowing?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I was pretty sure I heard in the news that Twitter decided to not allow auto following and unfollowing of users with their api or said that it no longer was to be done based on their terms of service.

I know that many Twitter applications you can buy like tweet adder and hootsuite don't allow this option anymore.

Does anyone know if it is still possible though?

I have an old php library that allows for the option to auto follow those who follow you as well as unfollow people who aren't following you automatically but it isn't working and before I delve into trying to fix it I want to know if anyone out there knows if it still can be done...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems, they actually had to much Spam etc.

Here is an article:

http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/08/why-twitter-finally-killed-the-auto-follow-for-good/